# Converting C++ Function to C# (String problems)

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to convert a code from C++ to C#, but I'm not being able to do it...

```
std::string Cipher(std::string Str) 
{
    char Key[5] = { 'H', 'S', 'M', 'K', 'V' };
    std::string Encrypted = Str;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Str.size(); i++) 
    {
        Encrypted[i] = Str[i] ^ Key[i % (sizeof(Key) / sizeof(char))];
    }
    return Encrypted;
}
```

What I got so far in C# is this:

```
    public string Cipher(string Str)
    {
        char[] Key = new char[5] { 'H', 'S', 'M', 'K', 'V' };
        string Encrypted = Str;
        for(int i = 0; i < Str.Length; i++)
        {
            Encrypted[i] = Str[i] ^ Key[i % ((Marshal.SizeOf(Key)) / sizeof(char))]; //line 29
        }
        return Encrypted;
    }
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only (on line 29)
```

I found out that it has something to do with immutability of strings, so I tried this:

```
    public string Cipher(string Str)
    {
        char[] Key = new char[5] { 'H', 'S', 'M', 'K', 'V' };
        string Encrypted = Str;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Encrypted);
        for (int i = 0; i < Str.Length; i++)
        {
            sb[i] = Str[i] ^ Key[i % ((Marshal.SizeOf(Key)) / sizeof(char))]; //line 30
        }
        return Encrypted;
    }
```

But, now I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (on line 30)
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: idioms in one language are not idioms in others. There are MANY differences, from sizeof(char) an many more

Comment: do not copy code with small changes - write algorithm in "native" style of target language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close! You are right to use StringBuilder. However, ^ -operator (bitwise XOR) makes C# intepret the result as int. Since you know it's still a char, just add cast:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Str.Length; i++)
{
    sb[i] = (char)(Str[i] ^ Key[i % ((Marshal.SizeOf(Key)) / sizeof(char))]); //line 30
}
```

Othewise I'm not sure if this does exactly the same as C++ implementation. `(sizeof(Key) / sizeof(char)` is basically the length of the array. So you should just use Key.length at C# implementation. So a bit more accurate one would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < Str.Length; i++)
{
    sb[i] = (char)(Str[i] ^ Key[i % Key.Length]); //line 30
}
```

Comment: @maccettura could you explain please?

Comment: Added clarification

Comment: @maccettura thanks both, the sizeof(char) can be there right?

Comment: @maccettura the code compiled with Marshal.SizeOf()

Comment: @maccettura please try, it DOES compile.

Comment: @SimoErkinheimo did not see the object overload.  Apparently I am just dumb today.

Comment: @charparodar change **(Marshal.SizeOf(Key)) / sizeof(char)** to **Key.Length**. It's not the same otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Encrypted[i] = Str[i] ^ Key[i % ((Marshal.SizeOf(Key)) / sizeof(char))]; //line 29
```

with

```
Encrypted[i] = Str[i] ^ Key[i % Key.Lenght]; //line 29
```

And you can replace characters in a string with:

```
"1234567890123".Remove(9,1).Insert(9,"A")
```

Using a string builder is a smarter choice though.

Comment: @maccettura care to explain? The C++ code calculates a modulo inside the "key" char array based on the running index `i` ofer the string to by cyphered. My C# replacement does the same, using the array method Length instead., both essentially Cycle the `key` array through based on the actual 'i'

Comment: @maccettura  Its not needed. Mashal.SizeOf(Key) is introduced by the Q.  This `Key[i % (sizeof(Key) / sizeof(char))];` is the c++ way to calculate how many elements are in the array of char that was defined above - not needed at all in C#

Comment: Ok so upon further research it looks like `sizeof(char)` returns a 1 in c++ so I apologize.

Comment: @maccettura if you had a c++ system with sizeof(char) == 3, then `(sizeof(Key)` with `key` an array of 5 chars in it would be `15` , therefore dividing by the charsize of 3 goes back to: `5 items in array` - your solution was still more complete then the accepted one ;)